# Connect two cube primitives on a single edge, hinge effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a video wall in a scene.  It has multiple "panels" that are currently using cubes.  I would like to attach these cubes to each other along a vertical edge so that they basically hinge and I can make adjustments to the entire wall more easily.  This is NOT for the game world, it is only for the editor. IE they will not move in game.

I found joints in the docs, but they seem to require a rigid body which I don't think I want.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: just make them all a child of an empty game object? its not "hinged", but you can move and rotate them all together (which i think is why you want that?)

Comment: Not exactly, I want the two cubes to always stay attached at one edge but be able to adjust the angle at which they are offset. The goal is to avoid adjustments causing a protruding edge.  Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: add more empties then? like you add an empty as "origin" of an individual panel. its not exactly a hinge either but once you aligned the empties and only rotate those it should behave similar. i know it sounds like a lot more work, and it certainly is, but it would be a out of the box solution. ofc another option is to look into editor scripting and create the very exact solution you need, which sure is the most work (but might be good training or depending on quality even something maybe could offer on the store)